# How to connect our own filter with the intel filter

Tags: c++, directshow, h.264

I am new to direct show.
I made a filter which takes the buffer as data and output the h264 data(not conform as not tested yet)But when i connect it in graph edit with intel h264 decoder it connects.
The problem i am facing is how to connect my own filter that i have created with intel h264 decoder?
Please guide.
I have created the filter using the link  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/158053/DirectShow-Filters-Development-Part-2-Live-Source
Some pseudo code or sample is most welcome.

Comment: Maybe you can start by posting your own codes.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor should i paste my filter code or the intel h264 decoder code?

Comment: paste the codes where you stuck right now

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Sir i am only able to create the live source filter i don't know how to connect it to decoder